# How to set permission "-rw-rw-r--" to file?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, permissions, chmod, chown

I have a file with permission `-rwxr-xr-x` in Ubuntu. How can I change it to `-rw-rw-r--`. I played with `chmod` settings, but was unable to get `-rw-rw-r--`.

Comment: Read [this page on Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes#Numeric_method)

Comment: You may want to go through [Unix/Linux Permissions - a tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Permissions.html).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Either

```
chmod a-x,g+w file
```

or

```
chmod ug=rw,o=r file
```

or using octal representation

```
chmod 664 file
```